# In Java is Exception is not handled in try catch id there is an if else in try block

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, exception

I am new to the Hibernate and Springs, now as I was developing a project I am unable to understand why this try catch block is not working.

The project structure is as follows:
JSP > Controllers > Services > Dao

I have a Bean named seller with necessary fields in it, which is passed to seller controller for making an update in database as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateSeller")
public String updateSellerProfile(Model model, HttpSession session, SellerFormBean seller) {

    int action = seller.getAction();
    try {

        if (action == 1 || action == 2) {

                //this modify seller Profile is giving an Exception of DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value  
                seller = sellerService.modifySellerProfile(seller);


                model.addAttribute("countries", commonService.getCountryDropdown());    
            }
        if (action == 3 || action == 4) {
            sellerService.modifyCaseStudies(seller.getSellerId(), seller.getCaseStudies());
        }



        Integer sellerId = (Integer) session.getAttribute("entityId");

        SellerFormBean bean=null;
         bean = sellerService.retrieveSeller(sellerId);

        Long userId = (Long) session.getAttribute("userId");

        try {
            UserFormBean user = userService.getUser(userId);
            bean.setUser(user);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            log.error("sellerController - updateSeller , getUser Failed ",e);
        }



        model.addAttribute("seller", bean);
        model.addAttribute("message", "Profile updated successfully");

    }catch(IllegalStateException e){
        log.error("sellerController - updateSeller : ",e);
    } catch (NullPointerException |HibernateException e) {
        log.error("sellerController - updateSeller",e);
        model.addAttribute("error",
                "Error occured while updating the profile. Please try again later. If the problem persist, then please conctact system administrator");
    }catch(Exception e) {
        log.error("sellerController - updateSeller",e);
        model.addAttribute("error",
                "Error occured while updating the profile. Please try again later. If the problem persist, then please conctact system administrator");
    }

    return selectTab(action);
}
```

Now I know that the error is where and how to correct that error but the problem is when there is an exception raised in method modifySellerProfile the exception is not caught within the try cath block of the controller. What could be the reason?

But when i use something like this in controller then exception is handled:

```
         try {
                //this modify seller Profile is giving an Exception of DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value  
                seller = sellerService.modifySellerProfile(seller);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Hello My Error I caught you",e);
            }
```

The modifySellerProfile is as follows:

```
 public void modifySellerProfile(Seller instance){
    log.debug("attaching dirty Seller instance");

     Seller sellerDo = new Seller();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(formBean, sellerDo, "caseStudies", "references", "accelerators");
      ///====Deliberately created an exception for testing
        instance.setCompanyType(null);

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(instance);

        log.debug("attach successful");

}
```

STACK TRACE :

```
<code>[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@fa47468]
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.htss.market.dao.SellerHome - attaching dirty Seller instance

[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.htss.market.dao.SellerHome - attach successful
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.htss.market.dao.UserHome - getting User instance with id: 72
Hibernate: select user0_.user_id as user_id1_21_0_, user0_.first_name as first_na2_21_0_, user0_.middle_name as middle_n3_21_0_, user0_.last_name as last_nam4_21_0_, user0_.title as title5_21_0_, user0_.photo as photo6_21_0_, user0_.phone_no as phone_no7_21_0_, user0_.email_id as email_id8_21_0_, user0_.country as country9_21_0_, user0_.password as passwor10_21_0_, user0_.created_by as created11_21_0_, user0_.created_on as created12_21_0_, user0_.updated_by as updated13_21_0_, user0_.updated_on as updated14_21_0_, user0_.last_login as last_lo15_21_0_, user0_.active as active16_21_0_, user0_.country_code as country17_21_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.user_id=?
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.htss.market.dao.UserHome - get successful, instance found
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.htss.market.dao.UserHome - attaching clean User instance
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.htss.market.dao.UserHome - attach successful



[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Committing Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com.htss.market.dao.Seller#37], EntityKey[com.htss.market.dao.User#72]],collectionKeys=[CollectionKey[com.htss.market.dao.User.userOtps#72], CollectionKey[com.htss.market.dao.User.passwordPolicies#72], CollectionKey[com.htss.market.dao.User.userEntityMappings#72]]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@8d70e98 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@d6e1acb deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@7e36f2ca orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4e5a4433 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@7ec930ae collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@38cd5fe collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4ae5d7e7 collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@56826954 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback after commit exception
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.htss.market.dao.Seller.companyType; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.htss.market.dao.Seller.companyType
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:182)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:683)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:565)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.htss.service.SellerService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d68f2f19.modifySellerProfile(<generated>)
    at com.htss.web.controller.SellerController.updateSellerProfile(SellerController.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.bufferAndPostProcess(ContentBufferingFilter.java:169)
    at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.doFilter(ContentBufferingFilter.java:126)
    at org.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:120)
    at org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.htss.market.dao.Seller.companyType
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:557)
    ... 83 more  </code>
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace

Comment: An exception don't disappear, it will be catch by the closest `try` and manage if it is define in the `catch` or "throw" again. Since you have a `catch(Exception e)` you will catch every exception, but not `Error`. Add your stacktrace to confirm that.

Comment: `Throwable` is the real base class, also from the checked `Exception`.  `DataIntegrityViolationException` might not be extending Exception but some RuntimeException which is another branch. Yeah, a bit inconsistent naming. Try catching `Throwable`.

Comment: @JoopEggen [DataIntegrityViolationException](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataIntegrityViolationException.html) extends `java.lang.Exception`.

Comment: Why the try-catch block in controller is not catching the Exception as raised by the modifySellerProfile() function , instead the whole project is termintaed with an exception and a 500 error on browser. How should i handle if the transaction was a failure ?

Comment: May be Exception is handled in some of the Hibernate class and not thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a check for `DataIntegrityViolationException` in Dao layer. Because it'll be caught there or Hibernate will handle/throw it. So it never reaches back to your service layer. 
This is because of this part of the code in `SessionFactoryUtils`

```
if (ex instanceof PropertyValueException) {
        return new DataIntegrityViolationException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
```

Do something like :

```
try {
  //Some code
} catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    log.error("Data Integrity Violation Exception "+e);
}
```